# Is animate/inanimate a grammatical category in German?

Tags: grammar

In Russian, each noun is either animate or inanimate. *Normally*, nouns denoting living things are animate, while the rest are inanimate. It is, in fact, not only a semantic, but actually a grammatical category since formation of some case-forms of the noun depends on whether it is animate or not (an interesting minimal pair example is the different declensions of the word мышь (mouse) depending on whether it refers to the animal or to the input device). Therefore, a dictionary lists *animacy* alongside other grammatical aspects such as gender.

Now, I was just reading [an article about da-words](http://yourdailygerman.com/2012/06/19/da-words-meaning-german/). Here’s a quote:

> I want to point out again that this whole *da*-thing is only done when you talk about things… like a table, a dream or a place. If you talk about a living being like a dog or a cat you wouldn’t use it. Those are treated like persons. But let’s do some examples and compare sentences with persons and things.

Several examples are then listed:

- Ich träume von ihr *(der Party)*. — wrong
- Ich träume davon *(von der Party)*.  —  correct
- Ich spiele mit ihr *(der Katze)*. — correct
- Ich spiele damit *(mit der Katze)*. — wrong

So it does seem that animate/inanimate distinction is important in German as well. So, my question, at the risk of being too broad, is twofold.

Firstly, what are other, if any, circumstances where the [animacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy) of a noun is important in German?

Secondly, sticking to the example of choosing between preposition+pronoun and the *da*-preposition, is the distinction of living vs. non-living so clear cut? I am asking because it very much is not so in Russian (for example a corpse (труп) is inanimate, while a dead man (мертвец) is animate). So here are some specific examples:

- *Ich träume von ihm* (dem Toten) or *Ich träume davon*?
- *Ich spiele mit ihr* (der Computermaus) or *Ich spiele damit*?
- *Ich denke an ihn* (den Organismus) or *Ich denke daran*?
- *Ich denke an ihn* (den Käfer) or *Ich denke daran*? (Living enough?)
- *Ich denke an es* (das Bakterium) or *Ich denke daran*?

This is not to say that I am interested only in these five words. I am interested in any corner cases where the distinction of living/non-living might be hard to determine mechanically.

Comment: Note that that blog is written by Emanuel, a German.SE regular.

Comment: @chirlu: Had the post been quietly edited, I might have not even noticed that the dative is changed into accusative. Now that that has been explicitly pointed out, every time I think of the verb denken I will immediately remember this post and use the correct case. So, if commenting about the mistake is useless/antiproductive for the GLU, it is certainly very useful to me as a learner :)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Which is why our preferred approach is correct *and* comment ;)

Comment: Gegenbeispiel: Ich spiele damit (mit dem Kätzchen).

Comment: @userunknown: Aha, great example! That's what I'm talking about, it can't be as simple as living/non-living. Hence the question.

Comment: @user unknown: I’d consider that wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of different declinations of мышь depending on animacy?

Comment: @Alex.S Not precisely what you are after, but my answer (if still survives) contains the example.

Comment: @Alex.S: Я вижу двух живых мышей и две компьютерные мыши.

Comment: _(irgend)wer, (irgend)was_

Comment: Never really thought about it, but it seems that truly inanimate and impersonal objects will practically always use *da-something*-pronouns, while persons (even metaphorical ones like the dead) and generally living beings will use normal pronouns (*ihm, ihr*,..). I do not agree with the *Kätzchen*-example, btw. I think, it may be a form of respect.

Comment: „Pronominaladverbien stehen nicht für Lebewesen, insbesondere nicht für Personen.“ „Pronominaladverbien stehen für Nicht-Personen (Dinge, Abstrakta).“ [Canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Pronomen/PronAdv/Funktion.html) Inanimate is the default, by the way, which is mostly relevant for questions: „Worüber lachst du?“ – „Über ihn!“

Comment: There is one more almost trivially obvious case, I assume in any language: *wer/wen/wem* etc vs *was* - analogous to *mit wem* vs *womit*.  *Wer ist das?* vs *Was ist das?*  One edge case would be the zoo, ie given a choice of animals or exhibits: *Wen willst Du zunächst besuchen?* is fine for children.  *Was* is a bit rough here.  *Welchen* or *Welches* is perhaps the happy medium.  Likewise given a choice between a motorcycle and a pony, it's a bit cold to the pony to say *Womit willst Du?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das ist eine gute Frage, oder besser gesagt: ein gutes Fragenbündel.

Ich antworte aus meinem Sprachgefühl, da ich keine Grammatik besitze und meine Suche im Netz nach *deutsche Grammatik belebt* nichts maßgebliches zutage gefördert hat.

> Is animate/inanimate a grammatical category in German?

*Belebtheit* wird im Deutschen (wie im Lateinischen) nicht als grammatische Kategorie geführt. Wir haben nur Kasus, Numerus, Genus (KöNiG).

Wer es nicht weiß: Im Russischen gibt es die Kategorie der *Beseeltheit* (одушевлённость) eines Substantives, und mit ihr ändert sich das Deklinationsmuster.

> Firstly, what are other, if any, circumstances where the property of the noun of being animate/inanimate (or living or not, if you will) is important in German?

Außer dem von dir genannten Fall (*womit? damit! mit wem? mit ihr!*) fällt mir nichts ein. Aber vielleicht übersehe ich etwas.

> Secondly, sticking to the example of choosing between preposition+pronoun and the da-preposition, is the distinction of living vs. non-living so clear cut?

Nein. Die Unterscheidung ist nicht scharf. Nehmen wir ein paar Beispiele.

*Da ist der Mond. Auf ihm sind schon Menschen gelandet.* (Wird zumindest behauptet.) Hier könnte man auch sagen: *Darauf sind schon Menschen gelandet.* Aber es wäre weniger respektvoll gegenüber dem Mond. Das ist nur eine Nuance, eine Feinheit. Bedenken wir: Heute ist der Mond ein Himmelskörper, aber früher war er ein Gott; heute tote Materie, früher lebende Kraft.

Indem ich das Pronomen durch *wo-/da-* ersetze, verdingliche ich den Gegenstand der Rede, mache ich ihn zum Ding. Mit Menschen und höheren Tieren geht das nicht, denn es sind einfach keine Dinge. Aber Regenwürmer (earthworms)?

*Hier sind Regenwürmer. Damit fängt man Karpfen.* Picture a dozen earthworms in a box or can, to be put on the hook when fishing for carps. Die Würmer sind zwar Tiere, aber man benutzt sie wie Dinge, wie ein Werkzeug. Auch hier kann man sagen *mit ihnen*, was ihnen einen höheren Status gibt.

*Ich hab ein neues Auto. Ich bin mit ihm sehr zufrieden.* Das Auto ist zwar ein Ding, aber man kann ohne weiteres *mit ihm* sagen, wobei *damit* genau so gut geht. Ersteres verleiht dem Auto Persönlichkeit, letzteres Dinglichkeit. Wie oben gilt: Es ist nur eine Nuance, nur eine Feinheit.

*Das ist Franz. Durch ihn hab ich Maria kennengelernt.* Franz ist ein Mensch, daher kann ich auf keinen Fall *dadurch* sagen; ich muß *durch ihn* sagen, sonst ist es falsch. Hier gibt es keinen Spielraum. (No wiggle room here.)

*Die Aufgabe ist schwierig. Kommst du damit klar?* Wenn hier jemand sagt *mit ihr*, wäre es für mich auch kein Fehler.

*Maria ist launisch. Kommst du mit ihr klar?* Maria ist ein Mensch, daher unbedingt *mit ihr*.

Was ist nun das Fazit? Der Ersatz des Pronomens durch *da-/wo-* geht nie für Menschen, nur manchmal für Tiere, meist oder immer für Gegenstände. Diese Regel ist für Lernende gut genug.

Jetzt fällt mir noch eine Analogie aus dem Französischen ein. Dort gibt es nämlich die gleiche Unterscheidung im Hinblick auf Lebewesen und Dinge:

- J'en ai entendu parler. = Ich hab davon gehört.
- J'ai entendu parler de lui/d'elle/d'eux. = Ich hab von ihm/ihr/ihnen gehört.

Wenn ich von Menschen rede, kann ich auch im Französischen das *de* Objekt nicht durch *en* ersetzen. Ich muß *de* plus Pronomen benutzen. Und im Italienischen ist es ganz genauso.

- Ne ho sentito parlare. = Ich hab davon gehört.
- Ho sentito parlare di lui/di lei/di loro. = Ich hab von ihm/ihr/ihnen gehört.

Vielleicht helfen diese Analogien ja irgendwem.

Comment: Stimmt alles, auch die Bemerkung zum Partitiv im Italienisch und im Französischen.  Allerdings ist es sehr schwer aus dem Bauchgefühl zu wissen ob etwas nicht vorkommt.  Die Frage war wirklich ob sowas noch wo im Deutschen vorkommt, und nicht zu den Feinheiten des einen Beispiels.

Comment: Sehr schöne Antwort. Um ein mögliches Missverständnis zu vermeiden - Folgendes ist auch richtig: "Maria ist launisch. Kommst du damit klar?" In diesem Fall ist dann *damit* kurz für "damit, dass sie launisch ist".

Answer (score 2):

I found [an academic paper](http://roa.rutgers.edu/article/view/712) claiming

> It is a well known fact about German that animacy plays a role in determining the word order of verbal arguments.

It is not so well known, and perhaps as much a function of emphasis as of animacy, and partly rules and partly preferences, but it is true: there are rules and preferences regarding the order of nouns and pronouns in cases where the verb takes multiple arguments.

We would not say:
*Ich wünsche alles gute Dir.*
Case plays a role, I am still seeking a good explanation of the rules.

Regarding Russian in equivalent situations, my instinct tells me that in Russian the word order is more free but also not completely free of preferences.  Which is really expected, what is marked explicitly on the word need not be marked by word order, and vice versa.

Comment: Die Regel ist doch ganz einfach … Dativ vor Akkusativ. Zum Beispiel: *Gib dem Motor mehr Zeit, daß er warm läuft.* Hat mit der Belebtheit nix zu tun. Und wenn ich höre *it's a well known fact that blablabla*, dann geht bei mir die rote Fahne hoch. Hab an der Uni viel akademisches Papier gelesen und sage daher frank und frei: Auch und gerade akademisches Papier ist geduldig. :)

Comment: Bin mit Dir da einig, ich bin sehr skeptisch, und Kasus spielt die Hauptrolle.  Aber *Ich gönne es dir.*   *Ich gönne es dem Mann.* (Akkusativ vor Dativ.)  Mit Pronomen gibt es Feinheiten.  Hätte gern eine ausführliche Erklärung mit allen Dimensionen.

Comment: Und im Fall Akk+Akk?  *Das frage ich Dich.*  (Obwohl *Ich frage es Dich.* oder *Ich frage Dich es.* beide etwas blöd klingen, ersteres mir aber ein Tick weniger.)  Und *Niemand würde mich das fragen.*  (*Niemand würde das mich fragen.* geht gar nicht.)