# How to express consequence?

Tags: single-word-request

> Am 13. November fand ein Angriff in Paris statt und mehr als 140 Menschen sind getötet worden.

Ich würde lieber etwas wie unten schreiben

> Am 13. November fand ein Angriff in Paris statt, __ mehr als 140 Menschen getötet worden sind.

Welches Wort passt am besten?

Comment: Am 13. September fand ein Anschlag in Paris statt, bei dem 140 Menschen getötet wurden.

Comment: Ich habe zwei Fehler korrigiert, die nicht von Bedeutung für die Frage sind. (1) Das korrekte Hilfsverb ist "sein", nicht "haben"  und (2) Nominativ für "Angriff" (Du kannst den Satz auch wiefolgt formulieren, dann ist es offensichtlich: "Ein Angriff fand in Paris am 13. Nov statt").

Comment: Darf ich auch bestätigen, dass "getötet wurden"die gleiche Bedeutung als "getötet worden sind" hat? Vielen Dank!

Comment: *sind getötet worden* klingt für mich holprig. Mir fällt gerade kein Satz ein, in dem ich nicht *wurden getötet* verwenden würde. Inhaltlich hast Du natürlich recht.

Comment: Alles klar Burki. Vielen Dank.

Comment: Um die implizite Korrektur im Kommentar von @Burki noch einmal auszuführen: _Angriff_ ist nicht der passende Begriff, besser ist _Anschlag_.

Comment: @chirlu: I wonder if *infolgedessen* can be used here?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: It can, but sounds strange because the deaths are not a _separate_ event, they happened during and as part of the attack. You could, however, say: _… gab es einen Anschlag in Paris. Infolgedessen wurden die Blutkonserven knapp._

Comment: @chirlu Im konkreten Fall wäre _Anschlagsserie_ noch passender – oder wenigstens Plural _Anschläge_.

Comment: @Crissov: Nja, wenn, dann _Anschläge_. Eine Serie war es nicht, denn die Einzeltaten fanden (mehr oder weniger) gleichzeitig statt; siehe auch den Unterschied zwischen _Serienmörder_ und _Massenmörder_. Es war aber ein koordiniertes Vorgehen, deshalb bin ich auch mit _Anschläge_ nicht ganz glücklich. – Wie nennt man denn die Ereignisse vom 11. September 2001 (vier parallel entführte Flugzeuge)?

Comment: Wikipedia nennt sie _Terroranschläge am 11. September 2001_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Am 13. November fand in Paris ein Anschlag statt, …*
>
> - ***bei dem** 140 Menschen getötet wurden.*
> - ***wobei** 140 Menschen getötet wurden.*
> - ***durch den** 140 Menschen getötet wurden.*
> - ***wodurch** 140 Menschen getötet wurden.*
>
> *Am 13. November fanden in Paris mehrere Anschläge statt, …*
>
> - ***bei denen** 140 Menschen getötet wurden.*
> - ***wobei** 140 Menschen getötet wurden.*
> - ***durch die** 140 Menschen getötet wurden.*
> - ***wodurch** 140 Menschen getötet wurden.*

[Another question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/is-animate-inanimate-a-grammatical-category-in-german) discusses whether “Pronominaladverbien”, like *wobei* and *wodurch*, only apply to animate referents.

If there is a relative clause following, it is often helpful, though not required, to put the noun in close proximity, so time and place move to the front here.
The sentence can be rewritten, of course, to do away with the sub-clause:

> - ***Bei einem** Anschlag*
> - ***Bei mehreren** Anschlägen*
> - ***Durch einen** Anschlag*
> - ***Durch mehrere** Anschläge*
>
> … *wurden am 13. November in Paris 140 Menschen getötet.*

Style guides for journalists often recommend to linguistically attribute actions by people to these people if possible. That means one should restrict the phrases with *(wo)durch* to earthquakes, thunderstorms etc., because it makes them personified agents, which is not appropriate for an assault where there are actual human acting. One could also replace passive *getötet werden* by active *sterben*, although some would deem that too harmless.

> … *sind am 13. November in Paris 140 Menschen gestorben.*
> … *starben am 13. November in Paris 140 Menschen.*

The humans killing others are still only implicit and anonymous with *(wo)bei*, but *Anschlag* then becomes situative information and rightfully so. This can be a good choice of wording when a fitting designation for them is yet unknown, uncertain or unavailable.

> - ***Bei einem** Anschlag*
> - ***Bei mehreren** Anschlägen*
>
> *… am 13. November in Paris töteten Terroristen 140 Menschen.*

The best order of phrases/words depends on the intended focus.

Comment: Zur Einordnung: An der Q gab es eine Diskussion zum Thema Sinn und Unsinn von Antworten-in-Kommentaren, die schließlich daran mündete, dass Burkis Antwort-im-Kommentar von mir in eine CW-Antwort überführt wurde, auf dass er wachse und gedeihe, ohne dass der Kommentar mit der naheliegenden Antwort andere Schreiber vom Antworten abhalten würde oder die Antwort zusammen mit den Kommentaren verloren gehen würde. Die Kommentare wurden bereinigt, so dass die CW jetzt leider relativ kontextfrei dasteht.